# Não está conseguindo detectar o objeto

Tags: javascript

Eu fiz um script de API, nesse script tem umas funções básicas bem utilizadas.
Estou no momento trabalhando na edição do IntervalsAPI:

```
var interval = {

    intervals: { },

    create: function(name, func, interval) {
        if(this.intervals[name] != null){
            c.e("[IntervalAPI] Interval with name `"+name+"` already exists!");
        }
        else {
            this.intervals[name] = setInterval(func, interval);
            c.t("IntervalAPI", "Interval `"+name+"` created. Total Intervals: " + _.size(this.intervals));
        }
    },

    delete: function(name){
        if(this.intervals[name] != null){
            clearInterval(this.intervals[name]);
            c.ti("IntervalAPI", "Interval `"+name+"` removed.");
        }
        else {
            c.te("IntervalAPI", "Interval `"+name+"` not found.");
        }
    },

    clear: function(){
        _.each(this.intervals, function(v,k){
            clearInterval(v);
            c.t("IntervalAPI", "Interval `"+k+"` removed.");
        });
    }
};
```

Quando eu executo `interval.create("teste", function(){ c.l("Is a Console.Log")}, 1000);`
aparece a mensagem normalmente que foi adicionado o interval. Porém quando eu tento remover `interval.delete("teste");` diz `undefined` e consequentemente a mensagem

> [IntervalAPI] Interval `teste` not found.

sendo que no interval.intervals tem o objeto { teste: ... } e não está retornando.

Comment: Se for exatamente como voce botou, voce ta criando "teste" e tentando deletar "test", ta com nome diferente

Comment: não :) está tudo igual,

Comment: eu errei mesmo na hora de digitar.

Comment: @sysWOW32 tentei reproduzir o problema, mas não consegui.: https://jsfiddle.net/8oam9my1/